How to enable Camera and microphone permissions for Safari (webkit) and firefox using playwright?
For my automation test using playwright, my browser need to have camera and microphone permissions. I am able to grant it for chromium browser but unable to do it for Firefox and safari (webkit).
Below is my piece of code which I tried.
For Safari:
const browser = await webkit.launch({
  headless: config.headless,
  args: ['--use-fake-device-for-media-stream']
})

For Firefox:
var browser = await firefox.launch({
  headless: config.headless,
  args: [
    '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'
  ],
  firefoxUserPrefs: {
    'permissions.default.microphone': 1,
    'permissions.default.camera': 1
  }
});

I am able to grant permissions for chromium using
context.grantPermissions(['camera', 'microphone'])

and the test is running successfully. But this does not seem to be working with Safari and Firefox browsers.

It is currently not possible:

Neither microphone nor camera permissions are supported for webkit yet

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11714

Firefox indeed doesn't support microphone permission.

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7635
